# What is the effect an average person feels when he/she meets a celebrity like Justin Beber or JFK in person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

What is the effect an average person feels when, for example, that person meets a Justin Beber or JFK in person?

I saw a documentary on JFK (I don't remember which one) once and they mentioned this syndrome where doctors in the hospital were tense and jittery ("don't know what to do, don't know what to say") during the time they were trying to bring 
him back after he was shot since they were operating on a celebrity of that stature.

The phrase used was some kind of social syndrome.

Like one could say cold feet syndrome....but cold feet is a medical symptom too so it cannot be used.

Comment: The first word that came to mind was that the doctors were 'awestruck'. Or, if they cannot speak, then they are 'dumbstruck'. However maybe you are looking for a technical word (?)

Comment: Keeping with the *-struck* theme, there is also *starstruck*, but that also does not fit with your "some kind of syndrome" description.

Comment: I strongly suggest that users reserve their answers for answers and not in comments.

Comment: Fyi, to get cold feet is an idiomatic expression in English.

Comment: It pretty much depends on the person. Meeting a random celebrity would have no particular effect on me. (In fact, I'd want to avoid meeting Justin Bieber . . .)

Comment: @Jason Bassford: I would too, but i am considering for the people who would and this is a question about them

Answer (score 0):

**be in awe of (someone or something)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/awe) an idiom

> To have a great amount of respect or admiration for someone, sometimes
>   to the point of feeling nervous or fearful around them.

As in:

> Everyone in town **was in awe** of the movie star as he came through on
>   his vacation.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate term for Justin Bieber would be 'starstruck', as Cobaltduck suggests, but this wouldn't be a suitable term for JFK's doctors.